# PyTorch Forecasting - Temporal Fusion Transformer calculate_prediction_actual_by_variable() plots empty

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning, encoder-decoder, self-attention, pytorch-forecasting

referring to the tutorial (https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/stallion.html) provided by Pytorch about their implementation of the Temporal Fusion Transformer, I'm trying to use their calculate_prediction_actual_by_variable() and plot_prediction_actual_by_variable() methods on a custom dataset.

Although the "*plot_prediction*" method works correctly, the resulting plots using "*plot_prediction_actual_by_variable()*" do not show any '*prediction*' or '*actual*' curve. E.g:

[Resulting Plot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/papzt.png)

Analyzing the tensors produced by the *calculate_prediction_actual_by_variable()* method, I realized that some *NaNs* values are present

[NaNs Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CPW8Y.png)

Has anyone encountered this problem?